# Switching languages for RequiredAttribute error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, data-annotations

I use custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` to translate error messages to different languages (translations are stored in database). Class looks like this:

```
public class LocalizationModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
                             IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
                             Type containerType,
                             Func<object> modelAccessor,
                             Type modelType,
                             string propertyName)
    {
        var localizationService = new Lazy<ILocalizationService>(() =>
        {
            return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILocalizationService>();
        });

        var attrs = attributes.ToList();
        var data = base.CreateMetadata(
                             attrs,
                             containerType,
                             modelAccessor,
                             modelType,
                             propertyName);

        var display = attrs.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (display != null && display.ResourceType == typeof(Resources))
        {
            data.DisplayName = localizationService.Value.Localize(display.Name);
        }

        var required = attrs.OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (required != null && required.ErrorMessageResourceType == typeof(Resources))
        {
            var errorResourceName = required.ErrorMessageResourceName;
            required.ErrorMessageResourceName = null;
            required.ErrorMessageResourceType = null;
            required.ErrorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorResourceName) ?
                string.Format(localizationService.Value.Localize(Local.Common.Required_validation), data.DisplayName) :
                string.Format(localizationService.Value.Localize(errorResourceName), data.DisplayName);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

I register it in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...            
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizationModelMetadataProvider();
    //...
}
```

Typical use case of these error messages is to declare a required field

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required_validation", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "Customer_name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
```

and display it on the view

```
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerName)
```

It works well - but only until user switches language. After that message for the RequiredAttribute remains translated in the old language. (Meanwhile DisplayAttribute is translated correctly.) Initial language can be any laguage, and RequiredAttribute message will be correctly translated to this language, but it looks like after first translation the message is somehow cached and is not translated any more.

When debugging, after the first hit of the line

```
var required = attrs.OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

`required.ErrorMessageResourceName` has correct value of `"Required_validation"` for property CustomerName, but after that, even after page refresh, it has *already translated value*. Why is that? How can it be fixed?